# Can Vuex's states of Nuxt be changed by client users?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Now I'm creating Nuxt App using another server credentials. What I wanna create is free plan user cant get premium contents. So I attach backend server created by Express which retrieve premium contents from the server in Nuxt App.
My Express server response contents filtered user's paid info to client. free plan user cant' get premium content from Express server, and only premium user can get premium content from it.

Thats my context.

So I have a question.
Can client user change Vuex state of Nuxt App?

I've searched many blog posts, I found that they use Vuex state to　figure out what users plan. For example, they put users account info on vuex state named authUser. And at each page needed login, they use vuex state's authUser to figure out if the user's account info.

But I think user can change vuex state, each page needed premium plan is easily viewed by free plan user. because of vuex state can be changed by client user.

Is my idea correct?
Please teach me about this question.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Of course, it can. Use authorization on server side.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
So why formal doc put authUser data on vuex state, and use it to figure out if user  logged in? If this code is working in web app, can user view pages needed login without login action?
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes

Comment: To decide which part of Vue app will be shown. This doesn't mean that premium data will be shown automatically. If a user tampers client-side app, empty premium view has to be shown. `/api/` endpont should respond with 403.

Comment: ahh I see! Thank you for your kind instruction!